Suggested meta tags when publishing a post
When I publish a post, Wordpress displays suggested tags in a dialog box.  If I don't click Add Those Tags after publishing my post, I can't find a way to redisplay the dialog so that I can add them after the fact.
Is there a way to redisplay those suggestions after I publish a page?


I'm not sure that I've ever seen this dialog... Could you include a screenshot?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This might be something that's handled by your theme or by a plugin you've installed; I don't think it's core WordPress behaviour. (If this is a site hosted on wordpress.com, you should check with their support.)
